# Advantages of null termination vs count variable

Tags: c, arrays, null-terminated

I need to use array of graph data, i.e. struct with x and y integers. This array will be passed through many functions, and I need to decide the API choice.

```
typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} GraphData_t;
```

How should I choose whether to use NULL-termination for the array, or supply count variable?

I have three approaches for my API:

```
1: loadGraph(GraphData_t *data, int count); //use count variable
2: loadGraph(GraphData_t *data); // use null-termination (or any other termination value)
```

```
typedef struct {
    GraphData_t *data;
    int count;
} GraphArray_t;

3: loadGraph(GraphArray_t *data); //use a struct which has integrated count variable
```

So far these seem equal to me. Which one would be the preferable method, and why?

Comment: Really need to see more of the other functions of the set and sample use cases.  (For me I would not use #2)  With #3, why `loadGraph(GraphArray_t data);` and not `loadGraph(GraphArray_t *data);`?  (add *)

Comment: Passing pointer to array together with count parameter is eligible way for passing arrays in C. Then it is up to API user to pass correct values - meaning to ensure that given memory area is valid.


So, from my pov 1. is ok.
Regarding point 3.: I would pass by-pointer not by-value.

Comment: Oh I just forget to pass by pointer on the last one. Edited and fixed

Comment: A big problem with "use null-termination (or any other termination value)" is that the "null" termination will be of type `GraphData_t;`, not a pointer to `GraphData_t`.  How is that "null" identified from a legitimate `GraphData_t;`?

Comment: How would`loadGraph(GraphData_t* data, int count);` work? As a "load" function how does the caller know when calling the function the value of `count`?  I'd expect the `count` to come _from_ the load.  Not enough detail here.

Comment: Generally, you should use a count variable since that gives much more efficient code. The whole concept of null termination is rather confused, the reason C dropped storing a separate size variable for arrays go back to 1970s Unix and the BCPL language... reasons that aren't very relevant today. Memory was expensive back in the days.

Comment: Don't forget you can have both: terminator **and** count!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a rather old dinosaur, I will use history here.

Anyway, the size + pointer idiom is *the* multi purpose and bullet proof way. If in doubt, use it.

The delimited way is just more common for human beings, specially when you want to initialize an array: no need to manually count the items (with the risk of a one off mistake specially if you later add or remove elements to the initialization list), you just add the delimitor as the last element. BTW, it is the way we use lines in text files... But anyway, the `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])` idiom allows to easily and automatically get the size...

The NULL terminated idiom comes from the begining of micro-processors, where code was close to the hardware for performance reasons: comparison to 0 was the fastest test, and memory was expensive. And programmers began to end their constant strings with a NULL character for that reason: only one byte overhead, even if the string was longer than 256 characters. You find reference to this ASCIIZ idiom in MS/DOS 2 manuals but it had been made popular by the pair Unix and K&R C language since the 70's.

It is still convenient, and still used in C strings, but many higher level tools like C++ `std::string` now prefere the counted idiom which does not require one forbidden value.

For daily programming, the (null) terminated idiom should only be used when an array can only be browsed forward, and when you have no special need for the size. But beware, if you simply want to copy a null terminated array, you have to scan it twice: once for its size and once for its data.

Comment: Thank you for answer, I feel more confident now. Would you suggest approach 1 or 3 to store the count? I.e. giving it as parameter, or within a dedicated struct.

Answer (score 3):

Null termination is a convention that can only be used if the null value is excluded from the set of legal values for the entries. For example the string array `argv` in `main` has a null pointer at the end because a null pointer cannot be a legal string.

In your case, the array elements are structures with 2 `int` coordinates. You would need to decide what values to consider invalid for these coordinates. If all values are OK, then you must pass the number of elements explicitly. Passing the array length explicitly is preferred in all cases, as it avoids unnecessary scans. Indeed `main` also gets the length of the `argv` array as a separate `int` argument `argc`.

Whether to encapsulate the array pointer and the length in a structure is a matter of style and convenience. For complex structures, it is preferable to group all characteristics in a structure, but for a simple array, it may be more convenient to pass a pointer and a size explicitly as it allows you to apply the function to a subset of the array with `loadGraph(data + i, j)`.

Answer (score 1):

While all approaches can of course get the job done, there are some differences which may or may not be relevant for your use-case.

- Null-termination is very convenient if the user needs or wants to use hard-coded arrays, because then they can just add or delete entries, without needing to worry about possibly breaking the application (unless they remove the terminator of course).
- Since the size is unknown, almost every function working with a null-terminated array needs to iterate over the whole thing. This might be a problem if the array is large, and many functions usually wouldn't actually need to access all entries (or not in the order they are stored).
- The terminator itself obviously needs to be a value that can never occur in your actual data. So, depending on your data, there might not be an obvious candidate to use as terminator (or even none at all).

There are probably more subtle differences which might influence your decision, but these are the first ones that came to my mind.